# How to implement javascript drag item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that's not working on my site but works when I test it elsewhere. In addition, on my site elements are duplicating twice, in testing it doesn't. I've tried implementing through a text widget, then placing code on the actual page. The problem is

1. Duplicate elements
2. The words should be draggable but aren't.
3. Malfunctioning widget area

[desktop](https://4309.co.uk)

https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/bGEbzxP

```js
var dragItem;
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;

container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);
container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

function dragStart(e) {
  dragItem = e.target;
  if (dragItem.xOffset == undefined) {
    dragItem.xOffset = 0;
  }

  if (dragItem.yOffset == undefined) {
    dragItem.yOffset = 0;
  }

  if (e.type === "touchstart") {
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - dragItem.xOffset;
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - dragItem.yOffset;
  } else {
    initialX = e.clientX - (dragItem.xOffset || 0);
    initialY = e.clientY - (dragItem.xOffset || 0);
  }

  console.log(initialX);
  console.log(initialY);

  //    if (e.target === dragItem) {
  active = true;
  //  }

}

function dragEnd(e) {
  active = false;
}

function drag(e) {
  if (active) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.type === "touchmove") {
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
    } else {
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
    }

    dragItem.xOffset = currentX;
    dragItem.yOffset = currentY;
    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background- color: white;
  display: flex;
  align- items: center;
  justify- content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border- radius: 7px;
  touch- action: none;
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0px;
  background- color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.5);
  border- radius: 50%;
  touch- action: none;
  user- select: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.container div:active {
  background- color: white;
}

.container div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border- width: 0px;
}

#gd {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#websites {
  background-color: blue;
}

#Identity {
  background-color: #ff0af3;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <div id="gd">Hello&nbsp;and</div>
      <div>
        <div id="websites">welcome</div>
        <div>
          <div id="Identity">to 4309</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally  decided to  implement the code on the home page (it's a WordPress site) and the widget area appears to be malfunctioning, but it's not showing up at all now. I have several `containers` so changed the `container` to `container6`. Didn't work. Tried removing `DOCTYPE and html` tags, as the page would already have `DOCTYPE` and I'd be calling it twice. Didn't work. Normally i implement home page changes through a text widget, but homepage code implementation should work also.

Comment: The problem is, "it's not working" on your site, and it's working elsewhere (in the Codepen you provided and in the snippet) so we can't see what's wrong

Comment: I know...... :-(

Comment: Is there something I'd need to change when implementing code on my site like removing `DOCTYPE` or something?

Comment: Tried removing `DOCTYPE` and `html` and didn't work.

Comment: Oh, there's probably something to change, but it's impossible to say what, because it's a complete blind guess. There's no way to reproduce, we can't see if there are errors in the console or anything :/

Comment: Also thought it might be the container size. But adjusting it didn't work.